# How to change name of name of Visual Force Page in Force.com Developer Console?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, developer-console

I'm wondering how to change the name of the name of my visual force page (.vfp) in the developer console. This page is hooked up to SalesForce as a tab, and it would be extremley inconvenient to delete the .vfp page and create a new one.

If someone can walk me through this process step by step on how to rename my visual force page, that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

:)

Answer (score 4):

If I have to rename it, I use the Setup menus. In your Salesforce go to Setup->Develop->Visualforce Pages, then click Edit on your page. You can edit the Label and Name at the top.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way in developer console to rename it pages.